# How to get the array element value which has no name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

In AngularJS controller, I am having the associative array called contact. I have to get the elements of the array which has no name. here I have posted my code and response for your reference

this is my controller code

```
   function onSuccess(contacts) {
               console.log(contacts);
            for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
              var list = contacts[i].phoneNumbers;
               console.log(list);
}
}
```

this my `contacts` array

```
[Contact, Contact, Contact, Contact, Contact, Contact, Contact, Contact]
0:Contact
addresses:null
birthday:Invalid Date
categories:null
displayName:"UIDAI"
emails:null
id:"16"
ims:null
name:Object
nickname:null
note:null
organizations:null
phoneNumbers:Array[1]
0:Object
id:"109"
pref:false
type:"other"
value:"1800-300-1947"
__proto_:Object
length:1
__proto_:Array[0]
photos:null
rawId:"17"
urls:null
__proto__:Object

1:Contact
addresses:null
birthday:Invalid Date
categories:null
displayName:"Distress Number"
emails:null
id:"17"
ims: null
name:Object
nickname: null
note:null
organizations:null
phoneNumbers:Array[1]
0:Object
length:1
__proto__:Array[0]
photos:null
rawId :"16"
urls:null
__proto__:Object
```

this my log of console.log(list) array

```
Array[8]
0:Array[1]
0:Object
id:"109"
pref:false
type:"other"
value:"1800-300-1947"
```

In here I have to get the element `value` from this.

Comment: `contacts[i].phoneNumbers.value` ?

Comment: i tried but it shows cannot read property of "value" undefined

Comment: ups didn't see, phoneNumbers is an array so `contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value` you may test if `phoNumbers` is defined and is not an empty array to return an empty string if so.

Comment: i will try it and tell you thank you budy

Comment: it works thank you budy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `phoneNumbers` is an array.

So you need to access it as `contacts[i].phoneNumbers[0].value`

You can also use lodash utility to get list of phoneNumbers only from contacts array. -Just For Info

Answer (score 0):

`list.value` will give you the value

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
           console.log(contacts);
        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
          if(contacts[i].phoneNumbers){
           var list = contacts[i].phoneNumbers;
           var value = list.value;
          }
        }
}
```